# Integration facebook api to iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

I try to walk through this tutorial [Facebook Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register)

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

My question: this command should be run via terminal, but where?

I have make git clone facebook api to Desktop and now it is on Desktop folder.

Which action I need to do that run this command line as above.

I mean action such as (cd Desktop - > cd facebook-ios-sdk ...)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's just given in your link itself.. Instead of working with scripts and making such a complex way of including facebook-ios-sdk into your project, why don't you just see the last line of this note. Yes. You can just drag and drop it to your xcode project folder.**

**Creating an iOS Facebook SDK Static Library**

If you create an iOS app that has Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) enabled then you should use a static library version of the iOS Facebook SDK instead of dragging in the files from the src folder. The latest release of the iOS Facebook SDK includes a shell script you can run to build the static library. You would do this through the command line by calling the build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh build script found under the scripts directory, for example:

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

This will create the static library under the /lib/facebook-ios-sdk folder (e.g. ~/facebook-ios-sdk/lib/facebook-ios-sdk). **You may then drag the facebook-ios-sdk folder into the app Xcode project to include the iOS Facebook SDK static library.**

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling for this for a long time, so the solution is, just paste the following:

~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh

into your terminal, then hit enter. Everything will be all set, you will have a new "lib" folder with the "facebook-ios-sdk/lib/facebook-ios-sdk" directory.

Hope this helps!