# new to command line and trying to build a script--what does this error mean?

Tags: xcode, ios5

I'm completely new to building scripts, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.  This was my input on Terminal:

```
Joels-MacBook-Air:~ joel$ /Users/joel/Desktop/NameOfApp/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

And this was the output I got:

```
Project Home: /Users/joel/Desktop
Start Universal facebook-ios-sdk SDK Generation
Step 1 : facebook-ios-sdk SDK Build Library for simulator and device architecture
/Users/joel/Desktop/NameOfApp/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh: line 56: cd: /Users/joel/Desktop/src: No such file or directory
Build settings from command line:
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator5.1
SYMROOT = /Users/joel/Desktop/build

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/joel/Desktop does not contain an Xcode project.
```

I assume the problem is clear from the above, but just in case here is the code for the script--if it's irrelevant, please ignore it:

```
!/bin/sh
/*
Copyright 2004-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.


This script will build a static library version of the Facebook iOS SDK.
You may want to use this script if you have a project that has the 
Automatic Reference Counting feature turned on. Once you run this script
you will get a directory under the iOS SDK project home path:
 lib/facebook-ios-sdk
You can drag the facebook-ios-sdk directory into your Xcode project and
copy the contents over or include it as a reference.*/

//Function for handling errors
die() {
echo ""
echo "$*" >&2
exit 1
}

//The Xcode bin path
if [ -d "/Developer/usr/bin" ]; then
//< XCode 4.3.1
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Developer/usr/bin
else
// >= XCode 4.3.1, or from App store
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
fi
XCODEBUILD=$XCODEBUILD_PATH/xcodebuild
test -x "$XCODEBUILD" || die "Could not find xcodebuild in $XCODEBUILD_PATH"

// Get the script path and set the relative directories used for compilation
cd $(dirname $0)
SCRIPTPATH=`pwd`
cd $SCRIPTPATH/../

//The home directory where the SDK is installed
PROJECT_HOME=`pwd`

echo "Project Home: $PROJECT_HOME"

//The facebook-ios-sdk src directory path
SRCPATH=$PROJECT_HOME/src

//The directory where the target is built
BUILDDIR=$PROJECT_HOME/build

//The directory where the library output will be placed
LIBOUTPUTDIR=$PROJECT_HOME/lib/facebook-ios-sdk

echo "Start Universal facebook-ios-sdk SDK Generation"

echo "Step 1 : facebook-ios-sdk SDK Build Library for simulator and device architecture"

cd $SRCPATH

$XCODEBUILD -target "facebook-ios-sdk" -sdk "iphonesimulator" -configuration "Release" SYMROOT=$BUILDDIR clean build || die "iOS Simulator build failed"
$XCODEBUILD -target "facebook-ios-sdk" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration "Release" SYMROOT=$BUILDDIR clean build || die "iOS Device build failed"

echo "Step 2 : Remove older SDK Directory"

\rm -rf $LIBOUTPUTDIR

echo "Step 3 : Create new SDK Directory Version"

mkdir -p $LIBOUTPUTDIR

echo "Step 4 : Create combine lib files for various platforms into one"

//combine lib files for various platforms into one
lipo -create $BUILDDIR/Release-iphonesimulator/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a $BUILDDIR/Release-iphoneos/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a -output $LIBOUTPUTDIR/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a || die "Could not create static output library"

echo "Step 5 : Copy headers Needed"
\cp $SRCPATH/*.h $LIBOUTPUTDIR/
\cp $SRCPATH/JSON/*.h $LIBOUTPUTDIR/

echo "Step 6 : Copy other file needed like bundle"
\cp -r $SRCPATH/*.bundle $LIBOUTPUTDIR

echo "Finished Universal facebook-ios-sdk SDK Generation"
echo ""
echo "You can now use the static library that can be found at:"
echo ""
echo $LIBOUTPUTDIR
echo ""
echo "Just drag the facebook-ios-sdk directory into your project to include the Facebook iOS SDK static library"
echo ""
echo ""

exit 0
```

What's my next step?

Thanks for the help, guys and gals.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the *current directory* the directory containing the `.xcodeproj` (special) folder:

```
(cd $PROJECT_HOME; xcodebuild -target ...)
```

Also `xcodebuild` should already be in your `$PATH` so you can dump all the stuff that sets-up `$XCODEBUILD`.  You can then select between Xcode installations using `xcode-select` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html)).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm ashamed to say, however, that I don't know how to do any of the things you suggest.  I don't want you to take the time and energy to type it out in excruciating detail--but by any chance do you know of a tutorial or resource I can visit to figure it out for myself?  I'm usually pretty good at finding that sort of thing but for the things you mention I'm coming up empty.  (In case it matters, I'm on a Mac.)

Comment: Got what I needed!  I followed the instructions in the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367513/integration-facebook-api-to-ios-app .  For what it's worth, I found a basic command line tutorial at http://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything that was helpful.